# Reporting Services 2008 SSRS usage metric reporting

Tags: ssrs, metrics

We use web trends to track the usage of our web sites, but web trends is currently not capable of reading the logs produced by SSRS 2008.  Has anyone figured out a way to modify the file so that web trends could read the log file data?  Is there another product that can be used to analyze the SSRS usage that you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these code samples from MS they use an ssis package to extract the report execution log. and come with several canned reports

http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2005!Server%20Management%20Sample%20Reports